# get the Object from super ActionListener | JAVA 8

Tags: java, java-8, hover, actionlistener

I want to forward the `ButtonStart01` to the `MouseListener`. So I can add a hover
effect to the button. What could be a valid approach to this? If possible I want
to solve it within the `public ButtonStart01() {...};` constructor.
When I use the commented `super.setIcon(imageIconHover);` it is referring to the `MouseListener`
instead of the wanted `ButtonStart01`.

```
package view.button;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class ButtonStart01 extends JButton {

     private static ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("src/start01.png");
     private static ImageIcon imageIconHover = new ImageIcon("src/start01_hover.png");

    public ButtonStart01() {
        super(imageIcon);
        super.setOpaque(false);
        super.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        super.setBorderPainted(false);  
        super.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(160, 60));
        super.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(160, 60));
        super.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                //super.setIcon(imageIconHover);
                System.out.println("in");
            }

            public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                //super.setIcon(imageIcon);
                System.out.println("out");
            }
        });
        super.setActionCommand("start01");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get a reference to the `ButtonStart01` inside `MouseListener` you should be doing:

```
@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent evt) {
    ButtonStart01 button = ButtonStart01.this;
    //Do whatever with button
}
```

And in order to call a `super` method inside `MouseListener` you should be doing (let's say I want to disable the button):

```
@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent evt) {
    ButtonStart01.super.setEnabled(false);
}
```

However, as I see, you use `super` keyword to call all `super` methods. This is ok, but it is not required. When you `extend` a class, and call a method that it is not overrided by the current class, the super method will be called.

What I want to say is, that if you simply `setBorderPainted(false);` instead of `super.setBorderPainted(false);`, it's the same thing. Because you don't `@Override` `setBorderPainted` method in `ButtonStart01` class.

Comment: `ButtonStart01.this.setIcon(imageIconHover);` I did like this and works like a charm
also thank you for the hint regarding the over stressed use of `super` in my class

Comment: That’s the literal answer to the question, but it’s worth mentioning that this approach is like reinventing the wheel. Just use [`setRolloverIcon(imageIconHover)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setRolloverIcon-javax.swing.Icon-) to set the icon for the hover effect. No need to implement your own mouse listener to do what the component already does. Further, you shouldn’t use `setPreferredSize` nor `setMinimumSize`. The button will already derive its size from the icon. You can set an empty border if you want additional spacing.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are add the MouseListener internally, I think @Override should get the result you want.

```
        super.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                super.setIcon(imageIconHover);
                System.out.println("in");
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                super.setIcon(imageIcon);
                System.out.println("out");
            }
        });
```